# using jquery, ajax and php to laod content on your site without reloading the whole page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am a newby in ajax and php and I would very much appreciate it if you could help me out. Seeing that I only know a little bit javascript and php I really don't know how to remedy this problem could you help me please! I've been hunting down a fix but couldn't find any, hopefully my search will stop here. I'll try my best to be clear in my explanation.

I would like this:

```
<a href="#" onClick="return false" onmousedown="javascript:swapContent('con1');">load html page called ducks</a>
```

to load into the myDiv area an html page called ducks.html.

I would also like that when I click on on this:

```
<a href="#" onClick="return false" onmousedown="javascript:swapContent('con2');">load a list of html links</a>
```

I would like it to load an html page with a list of links that when clicked will load into the myDiv area without reloading the whole page.

And lastly I would like to set up the myphpscript php file. To load a page with a list of links that will appear in the myDiv area and when I click on one of those links it will load likewise into the myDiv area.

This is my code

```
<!-- This is your PHP script... myphpscript.php --> 

<?php 
    $contentVar = $_POST['contentVar'];
    if ($contentVar == "con1") {
        include 'con2.html'; 
    } else if ($contentVar == "con2") {
        echo "<a href='con2'>View</a>";
    } else if ($contentVar == "con3") {
        echo "Content for third click is now loaded. Any <strong>HTML</strong> or text you  wish.";
    }
?>

<!-- This is the rest of my code -->

<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery-1.5.1.js"></script>
        <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
        <!--
            function swapContent(cv) {
                $("#myDiv").html('<img src="loader.gif"/>').show();
                var url = "myphpscript.php";
                $.post(url, {contentVar: cv} ,function(data) {
                    $("#myDiv").html(data).show();
                });
            }
        //-->
        </script>
        <style type="text/css"> 
            #myDiv {
                width:200px; height:150px; padding:12px; 
                border:#666 1px solid; background-color:#FAEEC5; 
                font-size:18px;
            } 
        </style> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="#" onClick="return false"  
           onmousedown="javascript:swapContent('con1');">Content1</a>
        <a href="#" onClick="return false" 
           onmousedown="javascript:swapContent('con2');">Content2</a>
        <a href="#" onClick="return false" 
           onmousedown="javascript:swapContent('con3');">Content3</a>
        <div id="myDiv">My default content for this page element when the page initially loads</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: hmmm... you require a lot of work here.

Comment: Why do new programmers always want to start with the coding equivalent of juggling chainsaws?

Comment: @Blazemonger Because they are too lazy to study. So they wanted the spoon-fed approach, they don't care if they understand the code or not, they want a working code, finished.

Comment: I have been studying just haven't made much progress.

Comment: Actually you can use jquery and css to handle this job. No need for php.

Comment: See this fiddle for a jquery+css solution (no php required) to your problem: jsfiddle.net/bYNeg [If this works, please also "accept" my answer, see my name].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this fiddle for a `jquery+css` solution to your problem [NO PHP REQUIRED]: http://jsfiddle.net/bYNeg/

Comment: Thanks this is the closest thing to what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: Yes, it is, no php required. Just modify the content inside the DIVs.

Comment: What if I wanted the links to be external. Like an html page called birds when I clicked on the link called content1 and loading another link called results of content1. Loading in the same way without refreshing the page. Do you mind if I asked what books you studied from to know all these things. I am currently reading some books but I feel as if am not reading in the correct order.

Comment: To handle external links, you needed to add more code and revise the existing code. The solution I provided you only handles content within the same page. I don't read books, I read articles, lots of articles from the net. You can google almost anything. Choose the technology you wanted to master. Master HTML first, then css, then jQuery, and if you require dynamic content which requires database, then add PHP + mySQL.

Comment: Okay thanks. I've already mastered html and css and I know a little mysql. So I'll just keep on reading articles and books then. Okay thanks again and have nice day.

Comment: Hey guys just wanted to say that I got it to work with the php file just like I wanted. Took a while but I finally figured it out. Thanks again for all your help guys really appreciate it.

Comment: great. now you're taking the stairs up the ladder of programming experience.

Comment: Yep but I still got a couple issues could you help me out like you did before with a jsfiddle answer.

Comment: Please!! If yes I'll post the question.

Comment: You can post the question and I'll try to answer if I can.

Comment: We can't discuss it here, this is off-topic. Let's move the discussion in a chatroom, but am not sure how to go to SO's chat yet.

Comment: And the following message just appeared. `user1477891 has only 8 reputation, not yet enough to chat`. If you have a gmail account we can Gtalk there.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me that if you want an external page to load when something is clicked, you need to perform an ajax GET or POST request, then print the results to the div:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

If you just want to change the contents of the div to some other text, you can use something like jQuery.html: http://api.jquery.com/html/

```
<script>
$("#idForLink").click(function () {
  var htmlStr = "The new text to show";
  $('#myDiv').text(htmlStr);
});
</script>
```

Without using jQuery, your example above is sending self posts to echo `contentVar` which will always refresh the page.

Comment: I'll try it and tell you the verdict thanks for helping me out I really appreciate it...

Comment: What I am looking to accomplish is something like this: <?php 
$contentVar = $_POST['contentVar'];
if ($contentVar == "con1") {
    include 'con2.html'; 
} else if ($contentVar == "con2") {
    echo "<a href='con2'>View</a>";
} else if ($contentVar == "con3") {
    echo "Content for third click is now loaded. Any <strong>HTML</strong> or text you wish.";
}
?>
?> but when {echo "<a href='con2'>View</a>"} link loads in the myDiv area and when clicked it loads out of the myDiv area on a new page.

Comment: Thanks for giving me some clarity about he above John. I didn't think about it quite like. You are all very brilliant. And words cannot express how grateful I am.

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply grabbing HTML from another file I would use the load method, as its quick and easy:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myDiv').load("someFile.html");
});
```

For more extensive requests you can use Post and Get. They allow you to pass data with the URL request in order to affect the results that are returned. Obviously your requested URL would need to be PHP/ASP and handle the request in this case.

Answer (score 0):

JAVASCRIPT:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

   // this is your mouse event (click) listener
   $('.destination_div').on('click','a',function() {
       var url = $(this).attr("href");
       $('.destination_div').load(url);
       return false;
   });

});​
</script>
```

Make your HTML anchors simple, do not include inline javascript, because the on("click") handles it already.

HTML:

```
<a href="http://yourhtml_containing_links.html">Your HTML with links</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help guys I really appreciate let me test it and see what I get...

Comment: Sorry but none of these works. You see the swapContent function is linked a php file called myphpscript.php and the links Content1, Content2 and Content1 are configured in the php file. in the myphpscript.php file is where I want set up where each link will load. Which is the in the myDiv. I found a way to load an html page in the myDiv area By putting this is the php block: if ($contentVar == "con1") {
    include 'con2.html'; and I managed to load links into the mydiv area my problem is that they won't stay in that area when clicked. Is there no way for me to fix this using the php file.

Comment: See this fiddle for a jquery+css solution (no php required) to your problem: http://jsfiddle.net/bYNeg/ [If this works, please also "accept" my answer, see my name].